# StructureMap 2.6+ Controlling Dispose Order

Tags: structuremap, zeromq

I am new to StructureMap and am using it to construct an app that uses clrzmq, which is a .NET implementation of ZeroMQ.

ZeroMQ apps work by creating a single context instance and, from that instance, creating one or more ZMQ sockets to send stuff around.

In order to cleanly shut down a clrzmq app, you need to first close and Dispose any connected ZMQ sockets created from the ZMQ context, and then, only after that is done, you Dispose the ZMQ context.

If you attempt to Dispose the context prior to closing & Disposing one or more of the sockets created from that context, the Dispose call on the context will hang and your app will not exit.

So, I am looking for a way to ensure that this Dispose order is obeyed by the StructureMap containers in this app.

I've tried a registry class with wiring like so:

```
For< ZeroMQ.ZmqContext >().Singleton();

Profile( "SomeProfile", p =>
    {
        // ZmqContext instances are created with a
        // custom factory method
        p.For< ZeroMQ.ZmqContext >()
            .Use( ZeroMQ.ZmqContext.Create() );

        p.For< ISender >()
            .Use< MyConcreteZmqSender >();
     });
```

...in the above, "MyConcreteZmqSender" is a class that creates a ZMQ socket using the ZMQ context instance it receives in its constructor (the only constructor argument).  It implements IDisposable, where the Dispose() implementation closes the created socket and calls Dispose() on it.

I also have a test case written to test out the Dispose behavior that looks like so:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestZmqSender()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize( x =>
        {
            x.AddRegistry<MyZmqRegistry>();
        } );

        ObjectFactory.Profile = "SomeProfile";

        ISender sender = ObjectFactory.Container.GetNestedContainer().GetInstance<ISender>();

        sender.doAllTheThings();

        ObjectFactory.Container.GetNestedContainer().Dispose();
        ObjectFactory.Container.Dispose();
    }
```

...in the above I tried using the nested container to get the Zmq sender instance, thinking that if I retrieve it that way, then if I later call Dispose on the nested cotainer, it will call Dispose on my socket sender before the ZMQ context gets disposed, which I assumed would happen when I called Dispose on the main parent container.

Alas, this does not appear to be what is happening, and this test case never completes.  I have verified that the sender is getting properly constructed with a reference to the singleton ZMQ context.  And, of course, if I manually call sender.Dispose() prior to disposing the main container, the test case completes successfully.

My first attempt didn't use the nested container at all, and it also hangs in the same way.

Anybody have any recommendations for how I can get this done without having to get a handle to all the sender instances and manually calling Dispose() on them and ensure that this is done prior to calling Dispose() on the main container?

Comment: Seems like a design flaw in ZeroMQ to me. Disposing the context should dispose its sockets as well.

Comment: it's not my favorite design choice, but it's consistent between both their Java and .Net implementations so it's one I have to work with for the moment.  I'm implementing a Java version of this same library that uses ZMQ but with Spring as the DI framework, and there it's not an issue because Spring appears to tear down objects in opposite order from their construction.

Comment: @Steven : coming back to this again.  So, you think I'm SOL trying to use SM to control this sequence?

Comment: At the moment, I'm thinking of wrapping the ZMQ context class, have the wrapper track socket references, and have it close any created sockets within its dispose method.

Comment: You can try Simple Injector, it guarantees opposite disposal when using scoped lifestyles.

Comment: Do note though that I'm a developer for Simple Injector. Be warned ;-)

Comment: @steven: thanks for the suggestion.  I don't know whether the single-thread constraint for lifetime scopes will get in the way in the long run, but for my current use I think it will be fine, and Dispose does what I need it to.

Comment: Currently, the LifetimeScope and WcfOperation lifestyles have a thread affinity. We're working on other lifestyles that don't have this limitation.